# Nesting aggregate within apply to aggregate multiple columns by multiple variables in R

Tags: r, aggregate, nested-loops, apply, summary

I have a dataframe with sets of scores, and sets of grouping variables, something like:

```
s1 s2 s3 g1 g2 g3
4  3  7  F   F  T
6  2  2  T   T  T
2  4  9  G   G  F
1  3  1  T   F  G
```

I want to run an aggregate, at the moment I'm doing:

```
aggregate(df[c("s1","s2","s3")],df["g1"],function(x) c(m =mean(x, na.rm=T), sd = sd(x, na.rm=T), n = length(x)))
```

I'd like to have just one line of code, so I could aggregate the multiple variables by multiple factors all at once.  Note I'm not trying to get a summary of s1-3 by combinations of g1-3 (as per answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9723208/aggregate-multiple-variables-simultaneously)). I've looked at `summaryBy` in the `doBy` package, but again that seems to do combinations of each factor rather than just an overall which isn't what I want (useful though!).  I've been playing with variants on:

```
apply(df[c("g1","g2","g3")], 2, function (z) aggregate(df[c("s1","s2","s3")],z,function(x) c(m =mean(x, na.rm=T), sd = sd(x, na.rm=T), n = length(x)))
```

But I get the error: "'by' must be a list" with that. I think I could work out how to do this with a `loop` and I know with various versions of `ddply` or `reshape` you can get aggregation but the most intuitive way (to me at least) seems to be an `apply` and `aggregate` - what am I missing?

Comment: What is the desired output?

Comment: I don't really mind, I was assuming a list. I prefer working with dataframes but it seems like reshaping the sets of output into a df is really a separate issue

Comment: @sjgknight  You could try `lapply(paste0('g',1:3), function(y) aggregate(cbind(s1,s2,s3)~., df[c(y,paste0('s',1:3))], function(x) c(mean=mean(x, na.rm=T), sd=sd(x, na.rm=T), n=length(x))))`

Comment: I've tried to produce a simplified example for reproducibility purposes but actually the colnames aren't as uniform as that, tried to adapt:
`lapply(c("IQ","PL"), function(y) aggregate(explor+sourDiv+sourQual+otherEval+Topic~., df[c(y,explor,sourDiv,sourQual,otherEval,Topic)], function(x) c(mean(x, na.rm=T), sd(x, na.rm=T), length(x))))`
I'm getting an "object 'explor' not found" error (but it is a named column in the df).

Comment: @sjgknight Check whether there is any leading/lagging spaces in the column names.  Also instead of `+`, you should use `cbind`

Comment: Thanks @akrun I like this not least because it's intuitive enough for me to understand! (I think: work through this list of factors (`lapply`) over this set of variables (1st bit of `aggregate`) `~.` by everything not used elsewhere, and use the lapply to create the right dataframe (`df[c(y,...)]`) ).

No leading/lagging blankspace but it's not working. Is the way I've set the lapply likely to work there?  (note there's a missing `)` between Topic~ which I've corrected in my code)

Comment: @sjgknight Ok, now I understand the problem,. It should be `df[c(y, 'explor', 'sourDiv', 'sourQual',...)]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let us name the anonymous function in the question as follows.  Then the `Map` statement at the end applies `aggregate` to `df[1:3]` separately by each grouping variable:

```
mean.sd.n <- function(x) c(m = mean(x, na.rm=T), sd = sd(x, na.rm=T), n = length(x))

Map(function(nm) aggregate(df[1:3], df[nm], mean.sd.n), names(df)[4:6])
```

giving:

```
$g1
  g1     s1.m    s1.sd     s1.n      s2.m     s2.sd      s2.n      s3.m     s3.sd      s3.n
1  F 4.000000       NA 1.000000 3.0000000        NA 1.0000000 7.0000000        NA 1.0000000
2  G 2.000000       NA 1.000000 4.0000000        NA 1.0000000 9.0000000        NA 1.0000000
3  T 3.500000 3.535534 2.000000 2.5000000 0.7071068 2.0000000 1.5000000 0.7071068 2.0000000

$g2
  g2    s1.m   s1.sd    s1.n s2.m s2.sd s2.n     s3.m    s3.sd     s3.n
1  F 2.50000 2.12132 2.00000    3     0    2 4.000000 4.242641 2.000000
2  G 2.00000      NA 1.00000    4    NA    1 9.000000       NA 1.000000
3  T 6.00000      NA 1.00000    2    NA    1 2.000000       NA 1.000000

$g3
  g3     s1.m    s1.sd     s1.n      s2.m     s2.sd      s2.n     s3.m    s3.sd     s3.n
1  F 2.000000       NA 1.000000 4.0000000        NA 1.0000000 9.000000       NA 1.000000
2  G 1.000000       NA 1.000000 3.0000000        NA 1.0000000 1.000000       NA 1.000000
3  T 5.000000 1.414214 2.000000 2.5000000 0.7071068 2.0000000 4.500000 3.535534 2.000000
```

**Note:** This could be shortened slightly by using `fn$` from the [gsubfn package](http://gsubfn.googlecode.com). It allows us to specify the anonymous function in the line of code that starts with `Map` using formula notation as shown:

```
library(gsubfn)
fn$Map(nm ~ aggregate(df[1:3], df[nm], mean.sd.n), names(df)[4:6])
```