# Aggregating multiple dependent measures

Tags: r, aggregate

I need to aggregate over a number of dependent measures (DMs) in R. I found the following discussion here quite useful:

[Aggregate / summarize multiple variables per group (i.e. sum, mean, etc)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9723208/aggregate-multiple-variables-simultaneously.)

Based on this, the code below basically does what I need. It gets quite lengthy, however, as the number of DMs increases (I have many DMs):

```
aggregate(cbind(DM1, DM2, DV3, DM4, DM5 ... DMn) ~ F1 + F2 +
           F3, data = sst2, mean, na.rm=TRUE)
```

I was therefore wondering if there was a more efficient way of writing the DMs, without having to individually type every one of them. Most DMs of interest are next to one another (i.e. `DM3`, `DM4`, `DM5` etc.), so I was thinking of using something along the lines of `cbind(DM1, DM3:DM10, DM14)`, but this doesn't seem to work. I also tried generating a list of the relevant column names. Unfortunately this didn't work either:

```
pr<-colnames(sst2)
pr2<-pr[pr!="DM2" & pr!="DM11" & pr!="DM12" & pr!="DM13"]
pr3<-noquote(paste(pr2,collapse=","))
pp<-aggregate(cbind(pr3) ~ F1 + F2 +
           F3, data = sst2, mean, na.rm=TRUE)
```

Any suggestions on how to efficiently include a large number of DMs in the aggregate function (or other related functions such as ddply) would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that this should work

```
sst2 <- data.frame(F1=c("A","A","B","B","C","C"),
                   F2=c("A","A","A","B","B","B"),
                   F3=c("D","D","D","D","D","D"),
                   DM1=c(5,6,21,61,2,3),
                   DM2=c(1,5,3,6,1,6),
                   DM3=c(1,7,9,1,4,44))

n = 3 # number of DM columns
m = 2 # number of F columns

DM <- paste0("DM", 1:n)

attach(sst2)

# use sapply(DM,get) but this produces separate columns
tmp <- aggregate(sapply(DM, get) ~ F1 + F2, 
                 data = sst2, mean, na.rm=TRUE)

detach(sst2)

# combine these separate columns. The apply is to each row of tmp
data.frame(F1 = tmp$F1, F2 = tmp$F2,
    DM = apply(tmp[(m+1):(n+length(DM)-1)], 1, mean))

#   F1 F2        DM
# 1  A  A  4.166667
# 2  B  A 11.000000
# 3  B  B 22.666667
# 4  C  B 10.000000
```

*Edit*

If your variable names are different than the only line that would need to change is

```
DM <- c("mean.go.RT", "mean.SRT", "mean.SSD", "SSRT")
```

If these variables are in your data frame, you could easily get them with

```
DM <- names(sst2)[4:6]
```

or whatever other columns (i.e. instead of 4-6) that you want

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick reply. I have just tried this out and get an error message at the call of the aggregate function: 

    > tmp <- aggregate(sapply(DM, get) ~ F1 + F2,
    + data = sst2, mean, na.rm=TRUE)
    Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : object 'DM1' not found

I did load the previous lines in your script as well (obviously). So, frankly, I am a bit puzzled why it cannot be found, as it should be loaded with sst2 and DM in your script. Any ideas?

Comment: Also, in my data the variable names are more diverse (e.g. mean.go.RT, mean.SRT, mean.SSD, SSRT instead of DM1-DM4). For my question here I had tried to simplify this a bit for the sake of clarity, but it seems that this simplification actually changes the solution somewhat - apologies for this! Nonetheless, trying to adapt your idea to my script, I receive the same error message:

pr3<-paste(pr2)
tmp <- aggregate(sapply(pr3, get) ~ F1 + F2, 
                 data = sst2, mean, na.rm=TRUE)
Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : object etc.

Do you know why this might be?

Comment: Yes I know - you need to ``attach`` the object, or get can't find it.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution using select, ddply and numcolwise:

```
library(dplyr)
library(plyr)

sst21 <- data.frame(F1=c("A","A","B","B","C","C"),
                   F2=c("A","A","A","B","B","B"),
                   F3=c("D","D","D","D","D","D"),
                   DM1=c(5,6,21,61,2,3),
                   DM2=c(1,5,3,6,1,6),
                   DM3=c(1,7,9,1,4,44),
                   DM4=c(2,3,6,7,2,33),
                   DM5=c(44,55,66,77,55,88))

sel1 <- dplyr::select(sst21, starts_with("F"), .data$DM1 : .data$DM3, .data$DM5) # select columns of interest
sel1 <- dplyr::select(sst21, -c(.data$DM4)) # Alternative: specifying columns to be excluded

sst22 <- plyr::ddply(sel1, .(F1, F2, F3), plyr::numcolwise(mean, na.rm = TRUE)) # Aggregate selected data
```