# dplyr group_by logical values

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm trying to simplify this with a few statements.  Not sure how to go about it (or if i can), but anyone that can get me close or as few steps as possible.  I am using dplyr and lubridate. I have a database called OutofRange (sample);

```
OutOfRange %>% select(OutRange, TouchVPOC)  
Source: local data frame [341 x 2]

   OutRange TouchVPOC

  (lgl)     (lgl)  

1     FALSE      TRUE  
2     FALSE     FALSE  
3     FALSE      TRUE  
4     FALSE     FALSE  
5     FALSE      TRUE

OutOfRange %>% select(OutRange, TouchVPOC) %>% filter(OutRange == T) %>% tally  
Source: local data frame [1 x 1]

      n  (int)  
1    37

OutOfRange %>% select(OutRange, TouchVPOC) %>% filter(OutRange == T, TouchVPOC == T) %>% tally  
Source: local data frame [1 x 1]

      n  (int)  
1    15

15/37  
[1] 0.4054054
```

So, if possible I'm looking for a final outcome of something like this, where CountofDataFrame is the count of all rows; where OutRange & TouchVPOC are the count of TRUE Values; and Pct = TouchVPOC/OutRange.

```
CountOfDataFrame OutRange   TouchVPOC    Pct
             341       37          15    .40
```

I do realize, I may be asking alot.. and I'm new to this, any suggestions are welcome. Just looking for a basis or a start in the right direction.

Comment: Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Comment: Some relevant *aggregate* posts: [R Grouping functions: sapply vs. lapply vs. apply. vs. tapply vs. by vs. aggregate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3505701), [Aggregate multiple variables simultaneously](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9723208), [How to sum a variable by group?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1660124)

Comment: To give you an idea, try `sum(c(TRUE, FALSE, TRUE))`.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you first get the data into tidy format first, then use group_by/summarize/mutate to do aggregation and percentage calculation like below.

```
a <- data.frame(OutRange = c(TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE), 
           TouchVPOC = c(TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE))

> a
  OutRange TouchVPOC
1     TRUE      TRUE
2    FALSE      TRUE
3    FALSE      TRUE
4    FALSE     FALSE
5    FALSE     FALSE

library(tidyr)
a %>% 
  gather(type, value, OutRange:TouchVPOC) %>%
  group_by(type) %>%
  summarize(true_count = sum(value)) %>%
  mutate(total = sum(true_count), Pct = true_count / total)

Source: local data frame [2 x 4]

       type true_count total   Pct
      (chr)      (int) (int) (dbl)
1  OutRange          1     4  0.25
2 TouchVPOC          3     4  0.75
```

Comment: Thank you!  Did not realize that tidyr works this way.  Opens new doors for me.  After running this, i realized that i will need  a pre step in filtering my data.  But i was able to add columns in the table, during the time of mutating the original data.   In other words, instead of filtering, i mutated a new column called OutRange_Touch; which did the trick!