# Replacing Missing Value in R

Tags: r, na

I have to replace the missing value to maximum (Value) by ID. How to do in R

```
ID Value
 1    NA
 5    15
 8    16
 6     8
 7    65
 8    NA
 5    25
 1    62
 6    14
 7    NA
 9    11
 8    12
 9    36
 1    26
 4    13
```

Comment: See these posts regarding grouping: [R Grouping functions: sapply vs. lapply vs. apply. vs. tapply vs. by vs. aggregate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3505701), [Aggregate multiple variables simultaneously](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9723208), [How to sum a variable by group?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1660124)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [R Grouping functions: sapply vs. lapply vs. apply. vs. tapply vs. by vs. aggregate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3505701/r-grouping-functions-sapply-vs-lapply-vs-apply-vs-tapply-vs-by-vs-aggrega)

Answer (score 2):

I would first precompute the max values using a call to `aggregate()`, and also precompute which rows of the data.frame have an NA value. Then you can match the IDs into the aggregation table to extract the corresponding max value.

```
maxes <- aggregate(Value~ID,df,max,na.rm=T);
nas <- which(is.na(df$Value));
df$Value[nas] <- maxes$Value[match(df$ID[nas],maxes$ID)];
df;
##    ID Value
## 1   1    62
## 2   5    15
## 3   8    16
## 4   6     8
## 5   7    65
## 6   8    16
## 7   5    25
## 8   1    62
## 9   6    14
## 10  7    65
## 11  9    11
## 12  8    12
## 13  9    36
## 14  1    26
## 15  4    13
```

Alternative, using `ave()`:

```
df$Value <- ave(df$Value,df$ID,FUN=function(x) { x[is.na(x)] <- max(x,na.rm=T); x; });
df;
##    ID Value
## 1   1    62
## 2   5    15
## 3   8    16
## 4   6     8
## 5   7    65
## 6   8    16
## 7   5    25
## 8   1    62
## 9   6    14
## 10  7    65
## 11  9    11
## 12  8    12
## 13  9    36
## 14  1    26
## 15  4    13
```

---

**Data**

```
df <- data.frame(ID=c(1L,5L,8L,6L,7L,8L,5L,1L,6L,7L,9L,8L,9L,1L,4L),Value=c(NA,15L,16L,8L,
65L,NA,25L,62L,14L,NA,11L,12L,36L,26L,13L));
```

---

## Benchmarking

Notes:

- I had to modify `bgoldst2()`, `rafa()`, and `akrun()` to guard against the case of zero non-NAs in a group; otherwise, `max(...,na.rm=T)` returns `-Inf` which can mess up subsequent operations. I used the same algorithm for all three guards. `thierry()` and `bgoldst1()` did not have to be modified.
- The large scale loop was fairly tricky to write, and I'm not going to attempt to explain all the details; feel free to ask follow-up questions if interested. Basically I ran 12 different benchmarks which varied by the number of groups and the frequency of NAs. The resulting table `res` shows the two parameters, the mean run-times for all solutions, and the unit chosen by the microbenchmark summarization algorithm.

---

```
library(microbenchmark);
library(dplyr);
library(data.table);
library(zoo);

thierry <- function(df) df %>% group_by(ID) %>% mutate(Value = ifelse(is.na(Value), max(Value, na.rm = TRUE), Value));
bgoldst1 <- function(df) { maxes <- aggregate(Value~ID,df,max,na.rm=T); nas <- which(is.na(df$Value)); df$Value[nas] <- maxes$Value[match(df$ID[nas],maxes$ID)]; df; };
bgoldst2 <- function(df) { df$Value <- ave(df$Value,df$ID,FUN=function(x) { nas <- is.na(x); if (any(!nas) && any(nas)) x[nas] <- max(x,na.rm=T); x; }); df; };
rafa <- function(dt) dt[ , Value := { nas <- is.na(Value); if (any(!nas) && any(nas)) ifelse( nas, max(Value, na.rm=T), Value) else Value; }, by = ID];
akrun <- function(dt) dt[, Value := { nas <- is.na(Value); if (any(!nas) && any(nas)) na.aggregate(Value, FUN = max) else Value; }, ID];
```

---

```
## small scale (OP's sample input)
df <- data.frame(ID=c(1L,5L,8L,6L,7L,8L,5L,1L,6L,7L,9L,8L,9L,1L,4L),Value=c(NA,15L,16L,8L,65L,NA,25L,62L,14L,NA,11L,12L,36L,26L,13L));
dt <- as.data.table(df);

ex <- as.data.frame(thierry(copy(df)));
identical(ex,bgoldst1(copy(df)));
identical(ex,bgoldst2(copy(df)));
identical(ex,as.data.frame(rafa(copy(dt))));
identical(ex,as.data.frame(akrun(copy(dt))));

microbenchmark(thierry(copy(df)),bgoldst1(copy(df)),bgoldst2(copy(df)),rafa(copy(dt)),akrun(copy(dt)));
## Unit: microseconds
##                expr      min        lq      mean   median       uq      max neval
##   thierry(copy(df))  955.804  989.1610 1043.2847 1004.984 1044.542 2852.016   100
##  bgoldst1(copy(df))  953.238 1005.1985 1069.6281 1039.410 1075.760 2968.337   100
##  bgoldst2(copy(df))  160.798  181.9665  196.0281  192.872  207.412  246.329   100
##      rafa(copy(dt))  947.679 1006.6945 1056.9396 1033.637 1055.874 2943.105   100
##     akrun(copy(dt)) 1327.862 1384.5255 1496.1259 1415.530 1445.894 3969.899   100
```

---

```
## large scale, 3 group sizes crossed with 4 NA densities
NV <- 1e5L;
NIs <- c(10L,1e3L,3e4L);
probNAs <- c(1e-3,0.05,0.4,0.95);
res <- expand.grid(NI=NIs,probNA=probNAs);
system.time({
    for (ri in seq_len(nrow(res))) {

        NI <- res$NI[ri];
        probNA <- res$probNA[ri];

        df <- data.frame(ID=sample(seq_len(NI),NV,T),Value=sample(c(NA,1:99),NV,T,c(probNA,rep((1-probNA)/99,99L))));
        dt <- as.data.table(df);

        ex <- as.data.frame(thierry(copy(df)));
        if (!all(c(
            identical(ex,bgoldst1(copy(df))),
            identical(ex,bgoldst2(copy(df))),
            identical(ex,as.data.frame(rafa(copy(dt)))),
            identical(ex,as.data.frame(akrun(copy(dt))))
        ))) stop('non-identical failure.');

        bm <- summary(microbenchmark(thierry(copy(df)),bgoldst1(copy(df)),bgoldst2(copy(df)),rafa(copy(dt)),akrun(copy(dt)),times=5L));

        nms <- sub('\\(.*','',as.character(bm$expr));
        for (nm in nms) if (!nm%in%names(res)) res[[nm]] <- NA_real_;
        if (!'unit'%in%names(res)) res$unit <- NA_character_;

        res[ri,nms] <- bm$mean;
        res$unit[ri] <- attr(bm,'unit');

    }; ## end for
});
##    user  system elapsed
##   73.18    0.00   73.37
res;
##       NI probNA    thierry  bgoldst1   bgoldst2       rafa       akrun         unit
## 1     10  0.001   7.850589 138.77128  14.867427   7.071150    8.023874 milliseconds
## 2   1000  0.001  40.318311 177.26223   9.868853   6.389129   18.054122 milliseconds
## 3  30000  0.001 813.204627 619.16166 125.274735  57.301590   74.732023 milliseconds
## 4     10  0.050   9.387743 139.41686  15.032158   8.479837    6.933616 milliseconds
## 5   1000  0.050  43.223697 156.79871  23.377797  20.550586  145.632279 milliseconds
## 6  30000  0.050 822.338773 677.81813 129.268155 114.585475  656.468438 milliseconds
## 7     10  0.400  15.955374 110.20717   9.785802  11.832889   10.511871 milliseconds
## 8   1000  0.400  55.858348 115.93900  14.441228  22.525058  142.740834 milliseconds
## 9  30000  0.400 853.571520 521.19690 147.925864 208.278328 2518.672465 milliseconds
## 10    10  0.950   9.768268  43.98346   5.921021   9.895623    8.571868 milliseconds
## 11  1000  0.950  49.228024  63.72596  13.702929  22.152230  143.606916 milliseconds
## 12 30000  0.950 822.033257 103.91700 113.398739  86.240922  630.982913 milliseconds
```

Comment: would you know why the following code doesn't work ? `library(data.table); setDT(df)[ , Value := ifelse( is.na(Value), max(Value), Value), by = ID]`

Comment: @rafa.pereira You have to add the `na.rm=T` argument to the `max()` call, otherwise any NA in the group will cause the return value of `max()` to be NA.

Comment: Oh!  of course ! Thanks so much, again. I've posted an asnwer giving you credit.

Comment: Note that the copy() function is not required for the benchmarking. And it distorts the comparing a tiny bit. copy() takes about  3 microseconds.

Comment: You can make the dplyr solution a bit faster by not using the pipes. `mutate(group_by(df, ID), Value = ifelse(is.na(Value), max(Value, na.rm = TRUE), Value))` gives me a speedup from 863 microseconds to 729 microseconds.

Comment: @Thierry The `copy()` call is necessary for the data.table-based solutions, since they modify the data.table object `dt` in-place (by reference). Without a `copy()` call, the first execution of any data.table-based solution function (either `rafa()` or `akrun()` for this question) would replace all NAs in `dt`, and so none of the subsequent executions of those solution functions would be proper benchmarks of the test case under examination. And because the `copy()` call must be included for data.table-based solutions, for the sake of fairness, it must be included for *all* solutions.

Answer (score 1):

```
library(dplyr)
dataset %>%
   group_by(ID) %>%
   mutate(
     Value = ifelse(
       is.na(Value), 
       max(Value, na.rm = TRUE), 
       Value
     )
   )
```

Comment: Thanks @Thierry for this solution... I always prefer pipe functions for data cleaning and preparation... When I read the question, exactly same thing came to my mind as your answer...

Answer (score 1):

A simple and fast solution using `data.table`. Thanks @bgoldst for the tip of including `na.rm=T`.

```
library(data.table)

setDT(df)[ , Value := ifelse( is.na(Value), max(Value, na.rm=T), Value), by = ID]
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `na.aggregate` with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
library(zoo)   
setDT(df)[, Value := na.aggregate(Value, FUN = max) , by = ID]
df
#    ID Value
# 1:  1    62
# 2:  5    15
# 3:  8    16
# 4:  6     8
# 5:  7    65
# 6:  8    16
# 7:  5    25
# 8:  1    62
# 9:  6    14
#10:  7    65
#11:  9    11
#12:  8    12
#13:  9    36
#14:  1    26
#15:  4    13
```