# R add empty row after 8 rows

Tags: r, formatting, dataset, rows

I would like to add an empty row after each 8 rows in my whole dataset. The actual one is like :

**original dataset**

[image]

and the final result I would like to get is :

**expected dataset**

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why would you ever add a row like that to your data? Do you just want to change how the data is printed rather than actually adding bad observations to your data.frame?

Comment: Because I need that format to be exported into an excel file where every each 8 rows I add an empty one. Since I don't know how to do that in macro I thought that I could do that in R and then export the file into the xlsx format .

Comment: But why do need that empty row? I can't think of a useful application for that.

Comment: Because I wanna compute the mean of all the 8 micro_rate items for each ID.

Comment: You can do that right in R instead of putting in an empty row.

Comment: Hi Adam, thanks for the tip. How would you do that?

Comment: [See this Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9723208/aggregate-multiple-variables-simultaneously)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer is for numeric columns.

Initially, for the first eight observations, you can generate a matrix that is a vector of ones with length 8 and an additional NA column: `v<- c(rep(1, 8),NA)`

and then you can kronecker product this matrix with the original: `kron(a,v)` (after applying `as.matrix` on both `a` and `v`).

this should be extendable for each 8th row using a loop.

For the character column, you can first separate it, `rbind` a `NA` row to each 8th element using a loop defined by `seq` and then `cbind` it back to the numeric matrix.

Answer (score 0):

```
cur <- rbind(df[1:8,], NA)
for(i in seq(from = 9, to = length(df), by = 8) {
    cur <- rbind(df[i:(i+7),], NA)
}
```