# How do I aggregate certain columns from data frame by a Unique ID?

Tags: r, aggregate, rscript

I have a list of statcast data, per day dating back to 2016. I am attempting to aggregate this data for finding the mean for each pitching ID.

I have the following code:

```
aggpitch <- aggregate(pitchingstat, by=list(pitchingstat$PitcherID),
                  FUN=mean, na.rm = TRUE)
```

This function aggregates every single column. I am looking to only aggregate a certain amount of columns.

How would I include only certain columns?

Comment: You want to specify a variable to aggregate - `aggregate(pitchingstat[c("var1","var2")], pitchingstat["PitcherID"], FUN=mean, na.rm=TRUE)` . Alternatively, use the formula interface `aggregate(cbind(var1,var2) ~ PitcherID, data=pitchingstat, FUN=mean, na.rm=TRUE)` . See this old answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/9723314/496803

Answer (score 2):

If you have more than one column that you'd like to summarize, you can use QAsena's approach and add `summarise_at` function like so:

```
pitchingstat %>%
group_by(PitcherID) %>%
summarise_at(vars(col1:coln), mean, na.rm = TRUE)
```

Check out link below for more examples:
https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/summarise_all.html

Answer (score 0):

Replace the first argument (`pitchingstat`) with the name of the column you want to aggregate (or a vector thereof)

Answer (score 0):

How about?:

```
library(tidyverse)
aggpitch <- pitchingstat %>% 
  group_by(PitcherID) %>% 
  summarise(pitcher_mean = mean(variable)) #replace 'variable' with your variable of interest here
```

or

```
library(tidyverse)
aggpitch <- pitchingstat %>%
  select(var_1, var_2)
  group_by(PitcherID) %>% 
  summarise(pitcher_mean = mean(var_1),
            pitcher_mean2 = mean(var_2))
```

I think this works but could use a dummy example of your data to play with.