# Vectorised approach to combine multiple observations

Tags: r, loops, dataframe, vectorization

I have not found anything remotely similar on SO (or elsewhere) and am therefore hoping for your help. I am not yet very familiar with finding vectorised approaches and my initial attempt feels quite clumsy.

I currently have a data frame similar to this:

```
df <- data.frame(c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3),c(TRUE,FALSE,TRUE,FALSE,FALSE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE))
colnames(df) <- c("ID", "Status")
```

I would now like to simplify my observations, showing TRUE only if every single status for the particular ID is given as TRUE, i.e. a final table like

```
ID    Status
1     FALSE
2     FALSE
3     TRUE
```

I have managed to do it in a loop (again, even for a loop it might be quite clumsy):

```
NrID <- df$ID[!duplicated(df$ID)]

for (i in NrID) {
  x <- sum(df$Status[df$ID == i])
  ifelse (x < max(NrID), df$Status[df$ID == i] <- FALSE, df$Status[df$ID == i] <- TRUE)
}

finaldf <- df[!duplicated(df$ID), ]
```

I would appreciate on advice or functions how to vectorise this approach since my final dataset is quite large and I would just appreciate a cleaner code.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Aggregate / summarize multiple variables per group (e.g. sum, mean)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9723208/aggregate-summarize-multiple-variables-per-group-e-g-sum-mean)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `dplyr` solution can be:

```
df %>%
 group_by(ID) %>%
 summarise(Status = all(Status))

     ID Status
  <dbl> <lgl> 
1    1. FALSE 
2    2. FALSE 
3    3. TRUE
```

Or with base R:

```
aggregate(df$Status, list(df$ID), function(x) all(x))

  Group.1     x
1       1 FALSE
2       2 FALSE
3       3  TRUE
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick and easy answer. I will mark it as correct as soon as SO allows (10 minutes). One question though: If I have a third variable, is there an easy solution to keep that as well? The third variable has the same value for each ID.

Comment: With `dplyr` you can do `df %>%
 group_by(ID) %>%
 summarise(Status = all(Status),
           third_variable = first(third_variable))`.

Answer (score 1):

If speed and concision is what you are after you might like `data.table`:

Setup:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df) # Convert to data.table
```

Calculations:

```
df[, .(Status = all(Status)), by = ID]

#    ID Status
# 1:  1  FALSE
# 2:  2  FALSE
# 3:  3   TRUE
```