# How can I sum all the values that has the same name r studio?

Tags: r, dataframe, aggregate

I want to make a graphic with the total positive cases of each city per year.

For example in Butte in 2006 there has been a total of (invented) 34 cases so I need this but with every city.

This is the data that I'm working with:
[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Aggregate / summarize multiple variables per group (e.g. sum, mean)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9723208/aggregate-summarize-multiple-variables-per-group-e-g-sum-mean)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
> aggregate(Positive.Cases ~ Year + County, FUN=sum, data=data)
  Year       County Positive.Cases
1 2006      Alameda             13
2 2006        Butte             93
3 2006 Contra Costa             40
4 2006       Coulsa             22
```

---

```
# Barplot
library(ggplot)
library(dplyr)

data %>%
  mutate(Year = factor(Year)) %>%
  group_by(Year, County) %>%
  summarise(Case=sum(Positive.Cases)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(Year, Case,fill=County)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position="dodge")
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For example,

```
aggregate(Positive.Cases ~ Year + County, data=df, sum)
```

You have the documentation here : [aggregate_function](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stats/versions/3.6.2/topics/aggregate)

Hope I was able to help you.

Comment: Oh thanks!!!!!! And how I implement that on a graphic?
Sorry for being that annoying but I don't understand R at all