# I am trying to sum rows in a column by a unique ID

Tags: r

I have a table of data that has a unique ID in the first column and then the next 5 columns have data. The first column has some rows that have the same unique ID. I want to sum add all of the rows with the same unique ID so my output only has one row for each of those unique IDs. I have seen some methods to do this over just one other column but I need it over 5 other columns.

Comment: Did you look at this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9723208/aggregate-summarize-multiple-variables-per-group-e-g-sum-mean It shows how to do it for multiple columns.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to use [dplyr](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/) to work with dataframe. Install it if you do not have.

```
install.packages("dplyr")
```

Assuming your dataframe is `df` with `ID` column and other *five* columns are numeric, this will sum all those 5 cols by ID.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>%
  summarise_all(sum)
```