# Group dataframe by column in R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, data-science

I have a dataframe `deliv` with the columns `date`, `name`, `region` and `count`.
Now I want to want to group by `date` and `name` so that `region` doesn't matter and `count` is summed up for every date/name-combination.

My idea was to use `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
df = deliv %>%
  group_by(date)
```

So not even that works; `df` is exactly the same as `deliv`. I don't know how to debug that piece any further. How do I group by (two) columns but the right way?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Aggregate / summarize multiple variables per group (e.g. sum, mean)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9723208/aggregate-summarize-multiple-variables-per-group-e-g-sum-mean)

Comment: or this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1660124/how-to-sum-a-variable-by-group

Comment: `group_by` in itself doesn't do anything (visually). You need to tell it to do something after that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at `summarise`:

```r
library(dplyr)
df = deliv %>%
  group_by(date,name) %>%
  summarise( total_count = sum(count) )
```