# R - create object from table within console whilst retaining format

Tags: r

I have some data from which I can create a table in the RStudio console using

```
#Open latest file
#get a vector of all filenames 
files <- list.files(path="MYFILEPATH",pattern="files.xls",full.names = TRUE,recursive = TRUE)

#get the directory names of these (for grouping)
dirs <- dirname(files)

#find the last file in each directory (i.e. latest modified time)
lastfiles <- tapply(files,dirs,function(v) v[which.max(file.mtime(v))])

File_List <- file.info(list.files("//MYFILEPATH", full.names = T))

Path_Of_Interest <- rownames(File_List)[which.max(File_List$mtime)]

library(readxl)
MyData <- read_excel(Path_Of_Interest,
    col_types = c("numeric", "skip", "skip", 
        "skip", "skip", "numeric", "skip", 
        "skip", "skip", "skip", "skip", "skip", 
        "skip", "skip", "text", "text", "skip", 
        "skip", "skip", "skip", "skip", "skip", 
        "skip", "skip", "skip", "skip", "date", 
        "date", "skip", "skip", "skip", "skip", 
        "skip", "skip", "skip", "skip", "skip", 
        "skip", "skip", "skip", "skip", "skip", 
        "skip", "skip", "skip", "skip"))

#Rename columns
MyData <- MyData %>%
rename(Age = "Age (Years)", Area = "Preferred Area", SeniorArea = "Preferred Senior Area", SaleDate = "Sale Date", ReturnDate = "Return Date")


#Group Age Column

MyData["Age"] = cut(MyData$Age, c(0, 17, Inf), c("0-17", "18+"), include.lowest=TRUE)

#Filter to most recent data only
MyData %>%
select(Age, Area, SaleDate) %>%
filter(SaleDate >= as.Date("2021-10-25") & SaleDate <= as.Date("2021-10-31"))

#Create table
table(MyData$Area, MyData$Age)
```

Raw data example here:

| ID | Area | Age |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | AreaA | 0-17 |
| 2 | AreaA | 0-17 |
| 3 | AreaB | 18+ |
| 4 | AreaB | 18+ |
| 5 | AreaB | 0-17 |

The output in the console looks like how I would like it to look, similar to below:

| Area | 0-17 | 18+ |
| --- | --- | --- |
| AreaA | 310 | 405 |
| AreaB | 210 | 401 |

However when I try to create an object out of this table (in order to merge it with another later) and then view the object I get a table like the below (not all rows included but you can see the column names)

| Var1 | Var2 | Freq |
| --- | --- | --- |
| AreaA | 0-17 | 310 |
| AreaB | 0-17 | 210 |

Can anyone please advise how to create the object to match format similar to the first table above for use in other things?

Basically I just need to be able to create an object which is the equivalent of an Excel pivot table with 'Area' for columns and count of 'Age' for rows.

Thank you!

Comment: Can you provide the code that you used to create the table object? A full minimum reproducible example would be best.

Comment: group and summarise the original data. Provide data-sample for exact answer... meanwhile: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9723208/aggregate-summarize-multiple-variables-per-group-e-g-sum-mean

Comment: I cannot reproduce your issue. With `tb <- table(Data$Area, Data$Age)`, I then `rbind(tb, tb)` and get four rows (`Area*`) and two columns (`"0-17"` and `"18+"`). Please show the code that is giving you problems, as it is not obvious.

Comment: My guess is that your mention of *"merge"* means that your `tb` is being converted to a frame, which means that the dim-names are placed in two columns and the third column is the number. The reason? the results of `table` and `xtabs` can include 1, 2, or more variables, which will be displayed on your console potentially in 3 or more dimensions (e.g., `xtabs(~ cyl + gear + vs, data = mtcars)`); when you want to do something frame-like with that, there needs to be a consistent way to convert `n`-dim to a 2d frame, so using columns for each dim-axis is a (only) sane way to go.

Comment: Thank you, I have added full code. Basically the code pulls in the most recent data file from a folder, then filters to my choice of date and provides row data which has 'Area' and 'Age' (age cut by 0-17 and 18+. What I'm looking to do is a pivot table, Areas as column and age as rows, a la an Excel pivot table? Thanks.