# Grouped means in collapse package

Tags: r, r-collapse

I am trying to calculate grouped means using [collapse package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/collapse/). Below is an example of what I am trying to achieve.

```
library(data.table)
library(collapse)

data_1 <- as.data.table(airquality)
var_means <- c(
  "Ozone",
  "Solar.R",
  "Wind"
)
data_1[,paste0(var_means,"_mean") := lapply(.SD,mean,na.rm = TRUE),by = .(Month)]
```

Comment: [Aggregate / summarize multiple variables per group (e.g. sum, mean)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61248352/1851712), by the author of the `collapse` package.

Comment: @Henrik it does not really answer my question because the original data then disappears.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are at least a couple of ways.  Using the `dplyr`-style syntax:

```
library(collapse)

var_means <- c(
  "Ozone",
  "Solar.R",
  "Wind"
)

airquality |>
  fgroup_by(Month) |>
  fmutate(across(var_means, fmean, .names = TRUE)) |>
  fungroup()
```

Or using `ftransform()`:

```
ftransform(airquality,
           fmean(
             list(
               Ozone_mean = Ozone,
               Solar.R_mean = Solar.R,
               Wind_mean = Wind
             ),
             g = Month,
             TRA = 1
           ))
```

Or if you want to pass a character vector of columns you need something like:

```
ftransform(airquality, 
           fmean(
             do.call(list, lapply(setNames(var_means, paste0(var_means, "_mean")), as.name)),
             g = Month,
             TRA = 1
           ))
```

Comment: can you please elaborate on the last one using character vector, looks a bit cryptic with setNames and str2lang

Answer (score 1):

A good answer you got by Ritchie. I would add that you can pass the function in a list to fmutate:

```
airquality |>
  fgroup_by(Month) |>
  fmutate(across(var_means, list(mean = fmean), .names = TRUE)) |>
  fungroup()
```

you could also use `ftransform` with compound pipes and the `add_stub`function:

```
library(magrittr)
airquality %>% ftransform(get_vars(., var_means) %>% fmean(Month, TRA = 1) %>% 
                          add_stub("_mean", pre = FALSE))
```

If you don't need to rename columns a simple approach would also be to use `settransformv`

```
settransformv(airquality, var_means, fmean, Month, TRA = 1, apply = FALSE)
```

comes very close to what you do with data.table. `apply = FALSE` here ensures we use `fmean.data.frame` applied to the whole subset of the frame, thus we only need to group once.

A final hybrid option you have is `fcomputev` with `add_vars<-` or `ftransform<-`, where the latter is more intelligent (i.e. it would replace columns if executed again) but the former is faster.

```
add_vars(airquality) <- airquality |> 
    fcomputev(var_means, fmean, Month, TRA = 1, apply = FALSE) |> 
    add_stub("_mean", pre = FALSE)
```